# best way to perform form validation android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, textview

There is a view with many editTexts I used this class to perform validation
the idea that for each input there is an `EditText` for input and `TextView` for error message

### MyCode

**First adding the form inputs**

```
  requiredFormViews.add(
            EditTextWithErrorTextView(
                editText_driver_phone_number,
                textView_driver_phone_number_error,
                String::isNotEmpty

            )
        )
```

**second the Validation call**

```
 private fun checkFormErrors() =
        requiredFormViews
            .map {
              it.performValidationAction()
                it
            }.all { it.isValidInput() }
```

**here is the class**

```
 data class EditTextWithErrorTextView(
        val inputEditText: EditText,
        val errorTextView: TextView,
        val isValidInputText: (String) -> Boolean
    ) {
        fun getInputText() = inputEditText.text.toString()
         fun showError() {
            errorTextView.visible()
        }
    
         fun hideError() {
            errorTextView.inInvisible()
        }
    
        fun isValidInput() = isValidInputText(getInputText())
    
        fun performValidationAction(){
            when (isValidInput()) {
                true -> hideError()
                false -> showError()
            }
        }
    }
```

my question how to improve the `checkFormErrors()`, in a way does need to return it and in one pass

Comment: Have you tried RxView for it is very convenient way of validating the views (multiple at a time)